# Putty autologin with port?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I have been trying to figure out how to make a Putty auto login shortcut, but I can't figure out to use it, if its using a custom port.

```
putty.exe -ssh root@1.2.3.4 -pw password
```

Comment: Might I suggest if you're going to setup SSH autologin, at least setup a public/private keypair instead of putting your password in a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

The [PuTTY Users Manual](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7.3.7) gives some help:

> The -P option is used to specify the port number to connect to.

To connect to a SSH server on port 2222 you would use:

```
putty.exe -ssh -P 2222 root@1.2.3.4 -pw password
```